# Sets that are both Sum-free and Product-free

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

Let $P_o$ be the primes excluding $2$. $P_o \subset \mathbb{N}$ has the following property $Q$:

- For any $a,b \in P_o$, $a + b \not\in P_o$.
- For any $a,b \in P_o$, $ab \not\in P_o$.

So both addition and multiplication necessarily leave the set $P_o$.

$P_o$ has [natural density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density) $0$.

> ***Q1***. Is there a set $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ with positive density
>   that satisfies property $Q$?

*Answered* quickly by @JoséCarlosSantos: *Yes*.
Permit me then to add a new question:

> ***Q2***. What is largest density $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ 
>   that satisfies property $Q$?

Santos's example has density $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Instead of adding a question after receiving an answer to your original question, you should ask that other question separately

Answer (score 26, accepted):

New answer:

Kurlberg, Lagarias and Pomerance, *On sets of integers which are both sum-free and product-free* ([arXiv:1201.1317)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.1317.pdf) answers the question.  The upper density of any such set is strictly less than 1/2, but can be arbitrarily close to 1/2.  I don't see that they state this explicitly in the paper, but it follows pretty quickly from Theorem 1.3.

Explicitly: Theorem 1.3 implies that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is some $n$ and some subset $S\subset\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ of residue classes that is sum-free and product-free consisting of at least $(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)n$ classes.  Then taking all integers in those residue classes gives a product-free sum-free set of integers of density at least $(\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)$.

Old answer:

Andrew Treglow's talk [*On sum-free and solution-free sets of integers*](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/%7Etregloac/bordeaux2016slides.pdf)  cites the following result of Deshouillers, Freiman, Sós and Temkin (1999):

> If $S\subseteq[n]$ is sum-free then at least one of the following holds:
>
> 1. $\lvert S\rvert\le2n/5+1$
> 2. $S$ consists of odds
> 3. $\lvert S\rvert\le\min(S)$.

Therefore, if the density of a sum-free product-free set $P$ of integers is greater than 2/5, then $P\cap[n]$ must fall in the second case for sufficiently large $n$.  (We can't be in the third case because $\min(P)<2n/5$ for sufficiently large $n$.)

So, the only way we could hope to do better than 2/5 is to use only odd numbers, and as a corollary the highest density we could hope for is 1/2.

In fact, the proof of Remark 2.7 of Kurlberg, Lagarias and Pomerance, [*Product-free sets with high density*](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/%7Ecarlp/productfree1128rev.pdf) carries over to the case of only odd numbers, showing that we cannot attain a density of 1/2.  For completeness, we repeat the argument here with the appropriate modifications: Let $a$ denote the least element of $P$, and let $P(x):=P\cap[1,x]$.  Since $P(x)\setminus{P(x/a)}$ lies in $(x/a,x]$, $\lvert P(x)\rvert\le \lvert P(x/a)\rvert+\frac{x-\lfloor x/a\rfloor}{2}+1$.  Also, multiplying each member of $P(x/a)$ creates products in $[1,x]$ which cannot lie in $P$, so we have $\lvert P(x)\rvert\le \frac{x}{2}+1-\lvert P(x/a)\rvert$.  Adding these two inequalities and dividing both sides by 2 gives $\lvert P(x)\rvert\le
\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\lfloor x/a\rfloor}{2}+2$, which implies that the upper density of $P$ is at most $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2a}$.

Answer (score 36):

What about $S=\{3n-1\,|\,n\in\mathbb N\}$? Its natural density is $\frac13$.

Comment: Very nice! ${}$

Answer (score 14):

This did not begin as an answer, but see edit below.

See [this talk](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/productfreetalk.pdf) by Carl Pomerance, on sum-free sets, and product-free sets.  One way to answer the OP (and this is the approach of the other answers) is to  choose an $n$, and a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, such that $S$ is both sum-free (if $a,b\in S$, then $a+b\notin S$) and product-free (if $a,b\in S$, then $ab\notin S$) .  Then, we take all integers that are congruent to an element of $S$, modulo $n$.  The desired asymptotic density is seen to be $\frac{|S|}{n}$.

This might not be a simple question at all.  Looking just at the sum-free property , we can easily get asymptotic density $0.5$ by taking the odd numbers.  The product-free property is quite subtle: the linked talk gives a construction of a very large $n$ (with over 100 million digits) such that there is an $S$ satisfying $\frac{|S|}{n}>0.5003$.    In fact, we could raise $0.5003$ to be arbitrarily close to $1$ (although no construction is given in the linked talk).  The general approach is to make $n$ have many small primes, to large powers, as factors.

One would not expect that this product-free set is also sum-free, but we can always remove some elements from it, until we have a subset of $S$ that is both sum-free and product-free.  I have no idea how big that resulting subset would be.

---

EDIT: Following the methods of the linked talk, choose $n$ (assumed even) and product-free $S$, so that $\frac{|S|}{n}\ge 1-\epsilon$.  Hence $|S|\ge n(1-\epsilon)$.  $S$ contains at most $\frac{n}{2}$ even numbers (since $S\subseteq \{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$, half of which are even).  Take $T$ to be the set of all the odd numbers in $S$.  We have $|T|\ge |S|-\frac{n}{2}=n(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)$.  Since $T\subseteq S$, $T$ is product-free.  $T$ is also sum-free, since the sum of two elements of $T$ are even (and hence not in $T$).  The asymptotic density of all naturals congruent to an element of $T$ modulo $n$ is $\frac{|T|}{n}\ge \frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$.

Note that an asymptotic density of $\frac{1}{2}$ is best-possible for sum-free sets (as proved in Pomerance's slides), much less sum-free product-free sets.  The above construction gives a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ arbitrarily close to this bound.

Comment: I am glad to know the terms "sum-free" and "product-free." Much more memorable than "property $Q$"!

Answer (score 11):

Let $S = \{n : n \equiv 2\ \rm{or}\ 3 \pmod 5\}$. This has density $2/5$, which beats $1/3$.

Incidentally, this sequence can be generated with a greedy algorithm, starting with $S = \{2\}$ and progressively adding every larger number that maintains the requirement.

Comment: This feels like it might be the max, because of the greedy property you mentioned.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Not necessarily: using a greedy algorithm starting at $1$ instead of $2$ leads to a different sequence that is not as dense: $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 27, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 45, 47, 53, 59, 61, \ldots\}$. (I'm surprised not to find this on OEIS. You might be interested in adding it there.) Other starting points are similarly bad. But it's interesting that the greedy method starting at $2$ gives a consistent structure, and I agree that it feels like it could be the best result.

Comment: @Théophile Doesn't 1*3=3 violate the constraint?

Comment: @Théophile   What it looks like you are doing is starting with 3 and running the greedy algorithm while restricting yourself to odd numbers; this will result in the set of odd numbers with an odd number of prime factors

Comment: @alphacapture, indeed, dropping the $1$ and checking OEIS for the rest gives http://oeis.org/A067019 . (It's generally a good idea to drop a few early terms when checking OEIS, especially $1$'s and $0$'s.)

Comment: @alphacapture Yes, my mistake; the $1$ should not be there... and I should know better than to doubt OEIS. ;)

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the title question is no. $Q$ doesn't characterize the odd primes, since, for example, $\{2,3,15\}\vDash Q$. Because $Q$ is the purely universal property $\forall x,y,z\,(x+y\neq z\land x\times y\neq z)$, any subset of a model is a model so, for example, any subset of the odd primes satisfies $Q$. You can also satisfy $Q$ by taking the odd primes along with any even integer $k$ and deleting one of every pair of primes that differ by $k$. Or forget about the primes altogether and take any (finite or infinite) set $\{a_1, a_2, \dots\}$ such that $2\leq a_1 < a_2$ and, for all $i>2$, $a_i > a_{i-1}a_{i-2}$.

Comment: I especially like your last example: $2,3,7,22,155,3411,\ldots$.